# Dell 9030 All In One - Secure Boot - Windows 10

Tags: dell, windows-10

We are experiencing an issue with the Dell 9030 AIO and Secure Boot. We have a custom Windows 10 image that when deployed with secure boot disabled, works as expected.

The issue begins when we enable Secure Boot in the BIOS of the machine. When the machine is restarted, it looks as if Windows is restarting then hangs on a black screen forcing us to power cycle the machine. We turn Secure Boot back off, we will see one normal restart. All consecutive restarts after that will hang on the black screen again like it did with Secure Boot enabled.

This is a domain joined machine recieving the same GPO's as a Dell Optiplex 9020 and a Dell Optiplex 7440 AIO which are not experiencing the same issues as the 9030. Both other models have Secure Boot enabled.

We have searched high and low, adjusted just about everything in the book to try and resolve this issue but we have not been successful.

The only thing that seems to resolve the issue is reimaging the machine with Secure Boot disabled and leaving it disabled.

Comment: Is there bios fully updated? I've seen similar behavior with one specific version one the 7030s.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `MDT` and `ADK` are you using? We have similar issues and found that if we update the `EFI` files on the `PXE` or `WDS` server the problem is resolved.

Essentially, the boot loader is not completing the `PXE` initialization. It then boots from the HDD as a fallback.

Comment: Can you please provide information on the version of MDT and ADK that you are using? Also it is generally not good to answer a question with a question. If you could answer the question with what works for you in more detail that would be amazing!